# Hibernate-search 5.0 spatial return no result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm creating a function that will enable user to search for nearby parking lots, which is 10km around the user's current location.

I'm using Spring Hibernate with MySQL5InnoDBDialect. And i tried to implement this function with the hibernate search 5.0.0.Final library by following this tutorial https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html/spatial.html#spatial-queries-distance

However no result was returned after i triggered the query. I'm using hibernate-core 4.3.7

Hibernate Settings

Note: file system provider = filesystem, indexbase = lucene/

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jinheng.fyp.bean" />
<!--  Naming strategy  -->
    <beans:property name="namingStrategy" ref="myNaming" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">15</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.default-lazy">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">false</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">4096</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">${hibernate.search.default.directory_provider}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${hibernate.search.default.indexBase}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.search.lucene_version">4.1.0</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Parking lot class

```
@Entity
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.HASH)
@Indexed
public class Lot extends BasicTable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer lotID;

private String lotName;

private String lotType;

@Longitude
private Double longitude;

@Latitude
private Double latitude;

private String address;

private String operationHour;

private Integer capacity;

private String availability;

//getsetmethods
```

Query DAO class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MapDAOImpl extends GenericDAO implements MapDAO {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Lot> getNearbyLot(Double latitude, Double longitude, Integer radius) {
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getSessionFactory());
    QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Lot.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = builder.spatial().within(radius, Unit.KM).ofLatitude(latitude).andLongitude(longitude).createQuery();

    org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Lot.class);
     //this code works
    // org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = getSessionFactory().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM LOT").addEntity(Lot.class);
    List<Lot> result = hibernateQuery.list();
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is buried in the documentation

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.4/api/org/hibernate/search/query/dsl/SpatialContext.html#onField%28java.lang.String%29

SpatialContext.onField(): basically if you don't provide the onField(), it does not work, it won't locate for you the name of the field to search on. 
This is a way to do that:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = spatialContext.onField("physical").within(100, Unit.KM).ofLatitude(centerLatitude).andLongitude(centerLongitude).createQuery();
```

"physical" here is the value of the property 'name' added to the @Spatial @Latitude and @Longitude (as seen in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html/spatial.html#spatial-multiplecoordinates)

My example:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity @Indexed  @Spatial(name="physical")
public class Tutorial implements IBusiness {

@Latitude(of="physical") @Column
private Double latitude;
@Longitude(of="physical")  @Column
private Double longitude;
[... cut ...]
```

It worked for me, and I hope it helps future readers. Lucene is a great API, Hibernate too, but they are way too broad... it is probably time to refactor the documentation a bit!